# How to settings.py for different environments (dev, production, etc.)

Tags: python, django

I have a several environments for my project. `DEV` for development, `BETA` for beta testing, `PRODUCTION` for production deployment. Each of these environments share lot of settings, but have different databases.

I was wondering if there is any elegant solution to maintain `settings.py` for different environments without duplicating them in another `settings.py` file (e.g. using inheritance)

Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Setting files are just python modules. Often, the following structure is used:

```
settings/
|-- base.py
|-- production.py
|-- development.py
```

Then, in your environment-specific settings, at the top of the file you import all common settings:

```
from .base import *
```

Then you point the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable to the appropriate settings module.

Comment: Example: https://awefsome.blogspot.com/2018/12/django-different-setting-modules-for.html

Answer (score 2):

As answered by @knbk django control their settings using **DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE**. But you will see that as soon you start using more settings based apps *(like oauth apps)* will lead you to forgetting about replicate custom variables across all the **settings.py** files.

To avoid this manual synchronization environment, i think the best way is setup a class based settings schemes. The one straight-forward way is to use this package [django-classy-settings](https://github.com/funkybob/django-classy-settings). With [django-classy-settings](https://github.com/funkybob/django-classy-settings) you can avoid missing to replicate custom (but common) settings.

On the documents we have a simple (example of the usage)[http://django-classy-
settings.readthedocs.org/en/latest/simple.html].

let say your project is like this:

```
myProj/
    manager.py
    myProj/
        setting.py
    app1/
    app2/
```

now you need to convert the **settings.py** to a folder

```
myProj/
    manager.py
    myProj/
        setting/__init__.py
    app1/
    app2/
```

Then, on the **settings/__init__.py**:

```
import os

import cbs


class BaseSettings(cbs.BaseSettings):
    PROJECT_NAME = 'myproject'

    # ... your general default settings ...


class LocalSettings(BaseSettings):
    # Settings for local development


class StagingSettings(BaseSettings):
    # ...

    DOCROOT = '/path/to/docroot/'

    def STATIC_ROOT(self):
        return os.path.join(self.DOCROOT, 'static', '')

    def MEDIA_ROOT(self):
        return os.path.join(self.DOCROOT, 'media', '')


class ProductionSettings(StagingSettings):
    DEBUG = False


MODE = os.environ.get('DJANGO_MODE', 'Local').title()
cbs.apply('{}Settings'.format(MODE), globals())
```

So you can now control the settings by a environment variable.

```
DJANGO_MODE=staging ./manage.py runserver
```

*(example from the docs!)*

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely take a look on Django classy settings.